# REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract fixed length string starting from a digit

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

```
Table A
ID     ID_Descr
1     'DUP 8002061286'
2     'DUP 8002082667  '
3     ' 8002082669 DUP'
```

I would like to extract the string from the ID_Descr field with the following conditions:

1. String always starts with 8
2. String length is always 10 digits

This means stripping everything to the right and left of the string (eg. '8002082669'). How can I achieve this? Using REGEXP_SUBSTR?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` but a regex is an expensive operation so you would be much better off using `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(ID_Descr, INSTR(ID_Descr, '8'), 10) FROM tableA;
```

If you really wanted to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` you could do it as follows:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID_Descr, '8.{9}') FROM tableA;
```

This would get `8` plus the following 9 characters (`.` being the wildcard).

Now if you wanted to match *only* digits, then `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` would probably be your best bet:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID_Descr, '8[0-9]{9}') FROM tableA;
```

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate you showing me the regexp query as well. It was perfect for what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Although you could use `regexp_substr()` for this, I would take a different approach.  I would just look for the `'8'` using `instr()` and then take the next 10 characters:

```
select substr(id_descr, instr(id_descr, '8'), 10)
```

This seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gordon!